# React-Native App: Unable to find ".js" files path

Tags: react-native

React-native app can't find my ".js" files path and I'm not sure why. I try couple of ways, for example:

> 1- '../components/LoginScreen' 2- './LoginScreen' 3-
>   './LoginScreen.js'

but same result.

Here is the error if someone can help me:

```
Looking for JS files in
   C:\Users\<User>\reactnewapp

Loading dependency graph, done.
 DELTA  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░ 70.6% (526/626)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2019:16:39:15 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./LoginScreen` from `C:\Users\<User>\reactnewapp\App.js`: The module `./LoginScreen` could not be found from `C:\Users\<User>\reactnewapp\App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `C:\Users\<User>\reactnewapp\LoginScreen(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
```

Even when I put the './' it doesn't offer me a path.

App.js :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import MainNavigator from './LoginScreen';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <React.Fragment>
      <MainNavigator/>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Folders screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the content of the _App.js_ file as well as a list of the files and folders in the directory?

Comment: In components folder there is only one js file LoginScreen, nothing else. But okay I will show you the App.js file.

Comment: Does the LoginScreen file has a .js extension?

Comment: You mean if there are some other files imported inside?

Comment: No I mean is the file called "LoginScreen" or "LoginScreen.js"?

Comment: It's called LoginScreen

Comment: Check out my App.js file

Comment: With Expo app it is working and It finds the path, but her in my react-native app it doesn't

Comment: Try renaming the file from `LoginScreen` to `LoginScreen.js`

Comment: I try it already, but same result

Comment: I am not talking about the import in your `App.js` file. You can omit the extension there. But the file itself must have a ".js" extension.

Comment: Yes it is .js file. I tought you want to try to import it in App.js like that.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your folder?

Comment: Okay, you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import a file called "LoginScreen" located in the same folder. But your file is in the `/components` directory.

Change your import to:

```js
import MainNavigator from './components/LoginScreen';
```

One dot is to indicate the current directory, which is what you want here. Two dots would be to indicate the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. But why it's different? In Expo project it is with two dots, or only './LoginScreen';

Comment: Maybe your App.js file was located in the `/components` folder in your Expo project?

Comment: No, this is brand new project. I worked before with Expo and now I start with react-native projects.